# xmgrace: how to add grid lines on the XY chart?

Tags: xmgrace

Using xmgrace with the following batch sctipt:

```
s0 line color "orange"
Major grid lines On
Minor grid lines On
HARDCOPY DEVICE "PNG"
PAGE SIZE 800, 600
xaxis label char size 2.2
yaxis label char size 2.2
xaxis ticklabel char size 2.0
yaxis ticklabel char size 2.0
```

I am looking for the command that would allow to add a grid doted lines on the plot and varry it style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
xaxis tick major grid on
yaxis tick major grid on
```

To enable the grid on each axis. The grid appearance can be varied by using

```
xaxis tick major color 2
xaxis tick major linewidth 2.5
xaxis tick major linestyle 3
```

(and similarly with `yaxis`)

Comment: Thank you very much ! just a question: where I could find info regarding different linestyles ? e.g. what is linestyle 3, 4,5 etc ?

Comment: I think it's hard coded. Just open xmgrace and look at the drop-down menu for any line styles: styles are sorted by type, so 0 is None, 1 is continuous, 2 is dotted, 3 is dashed, *etc.*

Comment: Right, thank you ! btw do you know if it's possible to use hex colors e.g. in the xaxis tick major color or it accept also either id like "1,2" or names like "blue" ?

Comment: You can do that by taking your template file, adding more colors to it and using the corresponding number. I don't think I have the space to explain how to do it here, but maybe you can make another question?

Comment: yes absolutely, it would be great, many thanks in advance !  feel free to contribute : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127417/more-colors-in-xmgrace