# xmgrace: adding title of the graph in batch mode

Tags: xmgrace

I am using a simple batch script to make a simple 2D graphs with xmgrace

```
s0 line color "blue"
s0 linewidth 2.5
HARDCOPY DEVICE "PNG"
PAGE SIZE 800, 600
xaxis tick major grid on
yaxis tick major grid on
xaxis tick major color "grey"
yaxis tick major color "grey"
```

What options could be added here in order that I could set the title of the graph on the plot and change it style (font id, color etc) ?

Are there any trick to take the title directly from the name of the file ?

Here is the expected output, where the tittle (in orange) were added in post-processing fashion using image-magic.
[image]